# UITextfield text color is not changing while not in focus

Tags: ios

So I have two `UITextFields`: name and amount and two `UIButtons`: income, expense.
When I press the expense button I want my `amount` textfield color to change to red or green if income button is pressed.

This only works if `amount` textfield is in focus, if `name` textfield is in focus, the color is not changed for amount.

Is there a way to change the color of the textfield if it's not in focus ?

edit:

Here is my code where I change the color:

```
@IBAction func typeBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == Buttons.expense.rawValue {
        amountTxt.textColor = .red
    } else {
        amountTxt.textColor = .green
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide your relevant code

Comment: @iPatel: updated with code.

Comment: did you put break point and checked?

Comment: Yes, the color is set in code, but the textfield is updated only after is in focus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems iOS uses by default attributedText and not text, that is why nothing is happening, and on focus it seems it takes your `textColor` into account, just do

```
let color: UIColor

if sender.tag == Buttons.expense.rawValue {
    color = .red
} else {
    color = .green
}

let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: amountTxt.attributedText!)

attributedText.setAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : color], range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))

amountTxt.attributedText = attributedText
```

This will then work as soon as button is pressed

**Swift 4 Xcode 10 edition**

```
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textField.attributedText!)
attributedText.setAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red], range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))
    textField.attributedText = attributedText
```

Answer (score 7):

After the textColor is set, the value needs to be reassigned to the textField.

```
textField.color = newColor
textField.text = text
```

Comment: This one worked for me. Probably a bit hacky, but at least it's less code than recreating an attributed string each time. :)